# How to find docker image name using given docker image ID?

Tags: docker, dockerhub

Assume I have follwoing image IDs which pulled from **docker hub** (not from my local computer):

```
aab39f0bc16d: Pull complete 
a3ed95caeb02: Pull complete 
2cd9e239cea6: Pull complete 
48afad9e6cdd: Pull complete 
8fb7aa0e1c16: Pull complete 
3b9d4fd63760: Pull complete 
57a87cf4a659: Pull complete 
9a31588e38ae: Pull complete 
7a0ac0080f04: Pull complete 
659e24e6d37f: Pull complete
```

How can I find the docker image name using given docker image IDs? or How can I find the actual URL of each Image ID above?

Note that these are image IDs that needs to be pulled when installing prometheus image (using `docker run prom/prometheus:v2.1.0` command)

Comment: What are you trying to do that you need this?  In a `docker run` context you can use the image ID directly; there may zero or multiple tags for a given hex ID.

Comment: @DavidMaze  need to find the docker image URL. Because we have a very tight firewall rules and need to add each docker image URL to the firewall one by one. They can't enable entire docker.io or docker.com domain. So, I need to find the dependencies URL too. To do that, I need to find it using image ID, because this is the output that `docker run` provides.

Comment: Are you going to download images only from docker.io?

Comment: @gumol Either download or add a firewall rule to enable download possibility using `docker run` command

Comment: @linker By downloading I meant "pulling". Hence you still need to add a firewall rule to allow ingesting docker.io. For your organization, is docker.io your only source of docker images?

Comment: @gumol No, we have our own registry. I find out the best solution might be pulling images in our registry and re-pull from there. But I'm not sure if it really works.

Answer (score 1):

I believe what you are looking for is the classic grep command in unix, this can easily solve you the problem:
`docker images | grep "xxxxxxxxxx"`

Cheers and good luck.

Comment: Actually I'm looking for the mentioned image IDs in docker hub. not in my local computer.

Comment: I guess he is asking to get the final image name from the intermediate image IDs + from Dockerhub.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing something

The hashs that you shared are representing different layers of an image. I'm assuming that this is the output of a docker pull command of a specific image

To get to know the image you just pulled, you can run 'docker history [image_id]', then all the different layers and the commands created them will show up

Comment: He is asking to get the full image URL from the image ID, not the layer IDs from that image

Comment: I understand, but there is no full image URL for each layer of an image. I tried creating the understanding of that by introducing the command

Answer (score 0):

Since your end goal is to whitelist a registry, you can put the docker daemon in [debug mode](https://success.docker.com/article/how-do-i-enable-debug-logging-of-the-docker-daemon) and watch the URLs used to get your image.

Example when I am downloading a centos image:

```
Aug 17 18:20:52 docker-machine: time="2018-08-17T18:20:52.690796940Z" level=debug msg="Calling POST /v1.24/images/create?fromImage=centos&tag=latest"
Aug 17 18:20:52 docker-machine: time="2018-08-17T18:20:52.691017261Z" level=info msg="{Action=create, Username=root, LoginUID=0, PID=32207}"
Aug 17 18:20:52 docker-machine: time="2018-08-17T18:20:52.691136349Z" level=debug msg="AuthZ request using plugin rhel-push-plugin"
Aug 17 18:20:52 docker-machine: time="2018-08-17T18:20:52.691681999Z" level=debug msg="Trying to pull docker.io/centos from https://registry-1.docker.io v2"
Aug 17 18:20:53 docker-machine: time="2018-08-17T18:20:53.129828996Z" level=debug msg="Using registries.d directory /etc/containers/registries.d for sigstore configuration"
Aug 17 18:20:53 docker-machine: time="2018-08-17T18:20:53.130051903Z" level=debug msg=" Using \"default-docker\" configuration"
Aug 17 18:20:53 docker-machine: time="2018-08-17T18:20:53.130065315Z" level=debug msg=" No signature storage configuration found for docker.io/library/centos:latest"
Aug 17 18:20:53 docker-machine: time="2018-08-17T18:20:53.130085358Z" level=debug msg="GET https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/"
Aug 17 18:20:53 docker-machine: time="2018-08-17T18:20:53.567233864Z" level=debug msg="Ping https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/ err <nil>"
Aug 17 18:20:53 docker-machine: time="2018-08-17T18:20:53.567270835Z" level=debug msg="Ping https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/ status 401"
Aug 17 18:20:54 docker-machine: time="2018-08-17T18:20:54.037436399Z" level=debug msg="GET https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/library/centos/manifests/latest"
Aug 17 18:20:54 docker-machine: time="2018-08-17T18:20:54.545501066Z" level=debug msg="GET https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/library/centos/manifests/sha256:fc2476ccae2a5186313f2d1dadb4a969d6d2d4c6b23fa98b6c7b0a1faad67685"
Aug 17 18:20:55 docker-machine: time="2018-08-17T18:20:55.008282140Z" level=debug msg="IsRunningImageAllowed for image docker:docker.io/library/centos:latest"
Aug 17 18:20:55 docker-machine: time="2018-08-17T18:20:55.008320868Z" level=debug msg=" Using default policy section"
Aug 17 18:20:55 docker-machine: time="2018-08-17T18:20:55.008329393Z" level=debug msg=" Requirement 0: allowed"
Aug 17 18:20:55 docker-machine: time="2018-08-17T18:20:55.008333896Z" level=debug msg="Overall: allowed"
```

In the case of docker.io, you will need to allow traffic with **registry-1.docker.io**. I am not sure you can restrict per image though. The best solution to restrict for images is to install an maintain your own docker image registry.